# best practice to push to GCM/APN from php

Tags: php, curl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently building a SNS for both web and iphone/android applications.

When an user writes on the wall or leaves a message, the server needs to push notifications to all related users. Users who are logged in on PC will receive it via Socket.io and those who are logged in on iPhone or android apps will get it via GCM/APN.

What is the best way to send push notification(GET) to all these users from a php web server?

cURL seems to do the right work but is extremely slow on my server.
The web server will need to send notifications to at least 3 different servers at once at unnoticeable speed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the process of building such an application and I have to be honest and advise you to use Zend Framework. There is also a lot of database planning to be done as read/writes to and from a database will be high. Specifically use Zend_Mobile or visit my blog for the gcm solution http://www.rogerethomas.com
Ideally you should run a cluster of servers processing messages and queues. Push messaging can get out of hand quickly and taking the time to plan it properly will pay off I promise you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My site is currently developed using Codeigniter and socket.io. I have chosen to use Socket.io to handle all the push related functions. After the user has written a message, server will return list of the members who should be notified and socket.io will send those to the push server.